# Can we disable this Windows 7 save dialog?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I positively detest the "Browse for Folder" save dialog in Windows, where instead of a "Save As" window where you have a number of (quick) ways to get to the folder you want -- paramount being the textbox where you can paste a drive/directory location directly -- you're forced to manually trawl through your drives' and directory structures with the ever-annoying manual arrow-dropdowns:

[image: Useless Windows save dialog]

Why can't we just have the "Save As" dialog for everything?

Is there a way to disable this dialog and force the "normal" save dialog? It seems completely random as to which/when programs use it. I've wondered if perhaps it'd be possible to disable access through Windows' API calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This folder tree thingy is the legacy dialog, whereas the new “Save as”-styled folder browser dialog has been available since Windows Vista.

Unfortunately, like Mario said, it’s up to the program when to show which dialog. Because their API is different, you cannot simply “flip the switch” and get the newer dialog.

Answer (score 2):

No, it depends on the actual program which common dialog is to be used. You can't override this choice.

Personally I'm not a real fan of programs abusing the file open dialog to select a folder. Just picking a path in a text box is usually the fastest way, so you shouldn't have to rely on any of the other dialogs at all.